# Check which of two values appears first after each record in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have the following table for the log of how a piece of equipment was used:

```
CREATE TABLE equip_log(run_id smallserial primary key, recipe smallint)
INSERT INTO equip_log(recipe) VALUES (1), (1), (2), (1), (3), (0), (1), (2), (1), (1), (0), (2), (2), (1), (2), (0), (1), (1), (3)
```

That gives:

```
 run_id | recipe
--------+--------
      1 |      1
      2 |      1
      3 |      2
      4 |      1
      5 |      3
      6 |      0
      7 |      1
      8 |      2
      9 |      1
     10 |      1
     11 |      0
     12 |      2
     13 |      2
     14 |      1
     15 |      2
     16 |      0
     17 |      1
     18 |      1
     19 |      3
```

Recipes #1, 2, and 3 are different ways of running the equipment. Recipe #0 is a maintenance procedure.

I want a query that returns two columns: the run_id for runs that used recipe #1, and then I want the query to look ahead at whether there's a future maintenance run (recipe 0) that comes before any other runs using recipe #1. So here's my desired output, with explanation for a few of the rows:

```
run_id | maint_next
-------+-----------
     1 | False        [Run #2 uses recipe 1, comes before the next recipe 0]
     2 | False        [Run #4 uses recipe 1, comes before the next recipe 0]
     4 | True         [Recipe 0 shows up before any other recipe 1's]
     7 | False
     9 | False
    10 | True
    14 | True
    17 | False
    18 | False        [Could become True if a maintenance gets logged next, but is False on current data]
```

Comment: Do you have a concrete problem? Have you tried anything and got stuck?

Comment: Heh, I guess I forgot to include a question. I'm just not sure how to do it. Maybe a CTE that creates a table with just recipe 0 and 1, and then assess whether the next row in that CTE has recipe 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `LEAD()` window function to check the next value:

```
 SELECT run_id, recipe, LEAD(recipe) OVER (ORDER BY run_id) = 0
 FROM equip_log
 WHERE recipe = 1 OR recipe = 0;
┌────────┬────────┬──────────┐
│ run_id │ recipe │ ?column? │
├────────┼────────┼──────────┤
│      1 │      1 │ f        │
│      2 │      1 │ f        │
│      4 │      1 │ t        │
│      6 │      0 │ f        │
│      7 │      1 │ f        │
│      9 │      1 │ f        │
│     10 │      1 │ t        │
│     11 │      0 │ f        │
│     14 │      1 │ t        │
│     16 │      0 │ f        │
│     17 │      1 │ f        │
│     18 │      1 │ (null)   │
└────────┴────────┴──────────┘
(12 rows)
```

---

Then just filter out the `recipe = 0` rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT run_id, recipe,
         COALESCE(LEAD(recipe) OVER (ORDER BY run_id) = 0, false) AS maintenance_next 
  FROM equip_log
  WHERE recipe = 1 OR recipe = 0
) s
WHERE recipe = 1;
┌────────┬────────┬──────────────────┐
│ run_id │ recipe │ maintenance_next │
├────────┼────────┼──────────────────┤
│      1 │      1 │ f                │
│      2 │      1 │ f                │
│      4 │      1 │ t                │
│      7 │      1 │ f                │
│      9 │      1 │ f                │
│     10 │      1 │ t                │
│     14 │      1 │ t                │
│     17 │      1 │ f                │
│     18 │      1 │ f                │
└────────┴────────┴──────────────────┘
(9 rows)
```

Comment: Excellent! I had thought that the LEAD() function just looked at the next row of the table; I didn't realize it could look at the next row of a subset of the table. This is perfect, thanks.